# How to exit multiple macros if file isnt located?

Tags: excel, vba

Call_Process call multiple macros, each one of them dependent on the previous macro. first macro gets the file location, followed by opening the file in that folder and the final one to close and save changes. The issue is if the opening file isn't there, the following macro will error out. How do I cancel the entire Call_Process if the file isn't located?

```
Sub Call_Process ()
Call File_Location
Call Open_File
Call Exit_WB
End Sub

**Sub File_Location ()**
location_db = "C:\Users\Documents\New folder\*.xl??"
End Sub ()

**Sub Open_File ()**
dim wb as Workbook
dim ws as Worksheet

if dir(location_db) = "" <- as you can see if the file doesnt exists, it exits out of Open_File sub but not the Exit_WB when im running the Call_Process
end sub
end if

wb_filename = wb.name
sheet_name = ws.name
End Sub


**Sub Exit_WB**
Workbooks(location_db).close savechanges=TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: Try on error goto: on your Call process?

Comment: Try just "end"?

Comment: `File_Location` should be a property or a function, if not just a plain `Const` declaration. `location_db` has no reason to be global, have `Open_File` take it in as a parameter instead. If the file doesn't exist, raise a run-time error *and handle it* in the calling scope (that would be `Call_Process`) using `On Error` statements to redirect execution to an early exit (`Exit Sub` should suffice) when an error occurs. An `End` statement would nuke all your global variables. Make `Open_File` a function that returns the `Workbook` reference so `Exit_WB` doesn't need to go look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truth be told, you'd need a bit more structure to your application. I don't think it's good practice to call SubProcedures that update global variables (unless there's a specific need for that). Take a look at my below example. `Call_Process` first asks a function for a file path. If it doesn't get one, the subroutine handles its own error messages. Once the path is available, it calls a function to open a workbook and leave a reference to said workbook. Again, if it doesn't work, the sub can handle it on its own.

Let me know if this helps out.

```
Sub Call_Process()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    filePath = GetDatabaseLocation()
    
    If filePath = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Set wb = GetDatabaseWorkbook(filePath)
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, couldn't open this file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Process whatever
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub


Private Function GetDatabaseLocation() As String
    Dim loc As String
    Dim fullPath As String
    
    loc = "c:\TempPath\*.xl??"
    
    'If the file doesn't exist, it will return an empty string
    'Otherwise, the file location. NOTE: DIR() returns only the file
    'name, so we will append the path below
    fullPath = Dir(loc)
    
    If fullPath <> vbNullString Then
        fullPath = "c:\TempPath\" & fullPath
    End If
    
    GetDatabaseLocation = fullPath
End Function

Private Function GetDatabaseWorkbook(sFilename As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    'If there is an error or something, will return 'Nothing'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilename)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set GetDatabaseWorkbook = wb
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code with on error also, should be working if error trigger:

```
Sub Call_Process ()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Call File_Location
Call Open_File
Call Exit_WB

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
End Sub
```

Comment: You should check that the file exists before opening it. Do not use error handling.

Answer (score -1):

when you say cancel out... you can use 'END' in the code. This will stop the entire code from running. one note, it wont actually tell you it's stopped so you might want to add a comment as a messagebox or immediate window. code would look something like this:

---

```
Sub Call_Process()
Call File_Location
Call Open_File
Call Exit_WB
End Sub

Sub File_Location()

location_db = "C:\Users\Documents\New folder\*.xl??"
End Sub

Sub Open_File()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

If Dir(location_db) = "" Then
    MsgBox "no file location"
    End
End If

wb_filename = wb.Name
sheet_name = ws.Name
End Sub


Sub Exit_WB()
Workbooks(location_db).Close savechanges = True
End Sub
```

---

Now if you want to expand and get specific messages, i would recommend you change them into functions with outputs/error handling.

Comment: As above - I'd identical solution posted later, so deleted it.